# Wacom Tablet CTH-680 not detected on Fedora 25?

Tags: usb, input-device, hardware-detection, plug-and-play

I know wacom tablets are a problematic to begin with since there's little official support from wacom. However I 've read in multiple forums that users had gotten their CTH-680 to start working easily.

*disclaimer: I am a newbie to linux*

I ran some command in terminal to check the connected usb devices, the name Wacom does come up but no recognition in the wacom tablet preferences in settings.

I read on Ubuntu forums that if you have the latest Kernel all you need is the input-wacom Drivers, in some cases they mention something called xf86-input-wacom server. I've attempted downloading the latest drivers from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/?source=typ_redirect.

I've had a certain degree of success installing input-wacom however I was unable to build the xf86-input-wacom drivers. I follow the instructions to the letter but I always fail to 'make'. I've installed all the prerequisites for the drivers and packages. The trend I see in all the tutorials I've seen is that non of them are meant for either fedora 24/25 its quite frustrating since at this point the wacom support should be plug and play.

If someone can just guide me through and help me in successfully installing my tablet, this is my last resort after extensively searching forums. Some forums and wikis got the touch and pen working but the wacom tablet drivers still failed to recognise the wacom which mean I was unable to click with the pen in certain application and no pressure or any sort of recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me say first that running Fedora as a newbie to Linux is possibly going to bring you this hassle as well as other potential hassles. Centos 7 can run GNOME 3 and will still give you the Red Hat type experience. Ubuntu and Linux Mint also have large user bases because they make things easy for beginners.

To your specific problem:

The problem is most likely that Fedora 25 is the first distro to run Wayland by default. Wayland is (roughly) a replacement for Xorg. Wacom's xf86 driver works with the Xorg driver. Wacom is not fully supported throughout the input stack in Fedora 25's Wayland. If you want to use Wacom with Fedora 25, disable Wayland.

See similar reports here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/5dylj0/fedora_25_wayland_wacom_as_primary_mouse_input/?st=iw2bhicu&sh=faef8ea3

If you don't pick another distro, you may need to ask a separate question about disabling Wayland. This page: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/WaylandByDefault#How_To_Test may give some assistance to more advanced users about how to do this.

Update: to switch to Xorg on Fedora 25 please see this post:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/96134/how-can-i-set-xorg-as-a-default-on-fedora-25/